# Implementing MySQL Spatial functions using Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, spatial

**Query 1:**

> "SELECT * from search_table WHERE column>=4"

**Eloquent ORM Implementation of 'Query1'**

```
$searchResults = SearchTempTable::select(*);

$searchResults = $searchResults->where('column', '>=', 4);
```

**Query 2:**

> "SELECT * FROM search_table WHERE 
>   ST_Intersects(column, geomfromtext( 'POLYGON(($point1X $point1Y, $point2X $point2Y,
>   $point3X $point3Y,$point4X $point4Y,$point1X $point1Y))'))"

How can 'Query 2' be implemented in Eloquent ORM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only `raw` statement will work for this.

```
$bindings = [$point1X, $point1Y, ... ];

SearchTempTable::whereRaw(
 "ST_Intersects(column, geomfromtext( 'POLYGON((? ?, ? ?, ? ?, ? ?, ? ?))' ))",
  $bindings
)->get();
```

Comment: `$searchResults = SearchTempTable::select(*);

$searchResults = $searchResults->where('column', '>=', 4);$bindings = [$point1X, $point1Y, ... ];

$searchResults =SearchTempTable::whereRaw(
 "ST_Intersects(column, geomfromtext( 'POLYGON((? ?, ? ?, ? ?, ? ?, ? ?))' ))",
  $bindings
)->get();`  Can we combine the raw statement with a normal where statement like this?

Comment: Yes, tried.It didn't worked for me.$searchResults  becomes empty after entering into `$searchResults =SearchTempTable::whereRaw( "ST_Intersects(column, geomfromtext( 'POLYGON((? ?, ? ?, ? ?, ? ?, ? ?))' ))", $bindings )`. The last executed query from query log returns the correct query. Executing that query in the database returns exact result set. Still, incorrect results from $searchResults->get()